# How to show image (type binary) from mysql on a view in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, database, image, laravel, laravel-4

I have the table users on mysql and added a column "image" which is a type binary (image png).
When I show the image on a view, I use this code :

```
<p>Avatar: {{Auth::user()->image}}</p>
```

but it shows something like that: �PNG  IHDR,,y}�u pHYs��tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyq�e<�nIDATx�� �Gy7����}K��]I�...

How can I solve this problem please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try use something like this:

`<img src="data:image/png{{-- change mime type if it's not png --}};base64,{{ base64_decode(Auth::user()->image) }}" />`

Comment: Thank you for your help but it didn't work (the image is not shown) so I make some changes on the code, like this :




<p>Avatar: <img alt="embedded image" src="data:image/png;base64,{{chunk_split(base64_encode(Auth::user()->image))}}"></p>

And now it works :) (y)